# What does ATC mean when they refer to "company"?

Tags: air-traffic-control, radio-communications, phraseology

Listening to LiveATC there are references by various ATC entities (towers, approach, etc) to "company". To what does this refer?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Generally when used in ATC movement instructions the word "company" means "The other aircraft operated by your *company*".
In this context it's a convenient shorthand for controllers and pilots: If two aircraft from the same operator are going to the same place on the airport (one may be told "Follow company"), or to assist with visual separation and sequencing on approaches.

In other cases it can mean "the airline (company) you work for" (such as being instructed to taxi to a ramp and "call company for your gate assignment" - the distinction is made based on the context of the request or instruction).

---

Note that this is *not standard phraseology*: despite being widely used [the term `company` does not appear in the pilot/controller glossary](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/pcg/C.HTM) or the [Air Traffic Controller's Handbook](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/ATC.pdf) .

Comment: Is it documented *anywhere*?

Comment: @Articuno I haven't seen it documented, but it is common knowledge in the industry. I have even heard it used when referring to other aircraft in a flight school fleet, although that felt kind of odd.

Comment: I've heard it too and I don't doubt your definition. I'm just wondering if it's even been written down, or talked about in an interview. Testimony from an ATCer would be ideal, but I don't think that is likely on record.

Comment: I fly out of a flying club.  Upon returning to home base, I have had Ground tell me to "hold for company traffic right to left on Alpha", referring to another plane in our club.  Clearly the definition of "Company" is informal.

Comment: Everyone.. we can all add our own personal stories. That doesn't add anything to this answer.

Comment: Is this a North-Americanism? Is it used in EU and rest-of-world? (Q isn't tagged FAA)

Comment: [Here](http://asrs.arc.nasa.gov/publications/directline/dl7_say.htm) is a possible reference. It says "*The Controller, with no warning or explanation called, '[Air Carrier X], the traffic you're following is turning final for Runway 26, a company [jet]*", referring to it as "non-standard phraseology".

Comment: Here's the full report in the ASRS database: http://akama.arc.nasa.gov/ASRSDBOnline/QueryWizard_Display.aspx?server=ASRSO

Comment: There are also discrete "company frequencies" which are assigned to (some?) airlines for letting aircraft communicate with some airline ground facility. I know of at least one where the call sign of the ground facility is simply "COMPANY".

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Heard it from ATC in the UK referring to a flying school trainer, so not just North America, and not just airlines.

Comment: @abelenky Yeah they do that at my home field - sometimes it's obvious (All the Farmingdale State College planes look the same, all the Ventura Aviation planes have the same scheme with different tail colors), other times it's not (the Nassau Flyers fleet has a bunch of planes on leaseback with varying paint schemes). Usually you can figure it out, but if you don't know the fleets it can be confusing for a new student.

Comment: Yes, JAL trains at KAPC in twin pipers, and ATC routinely calls them "company traffic" to their brethren.

Comment: re: *"the distinction is made based on the context of the request or instruction)."* – shouldn't ATC language be unequivocal ? I thought that was one of two of its hallmarks: short and unequivocal.

Comment: @summerrain One example refers to company planes, the other to company dispatchers.  Both obviously reference the same idea ("the company you work for") applied in a way that makes sense in the given context, so there's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 16):

It means, "The same airline as you".

The typical communication is:

> "Cactus 123: You are cleared to land, 31L. Following Company Traffic on a 2 mile final"

Which means:

> "You are following another US Airways flight, that is currently 2 miles from the runway"

It helps the pilot identify the airplane out in front of him. For example, if he spots a Red and Blue Southwest plane, he knows he's not looking at the proper plane!  He knows he needs to be looking for another US Air paint scheme.

Comment: So, when an emergency aircraft is attempting to 'figure out where to go" when touched down (with a low tire, but emergency services determined the plane could be moved) and the PIC is asked by Ground "do you need to call company", the pilot whips out his iPhone?

Comment: That is an entirely different context, (and outside my expertise).  The PIC has a different communications channel to his company's dispatch center.  (I think it is a separate radio frequency, but I'm not sure)

Comment: @abelenky: It can be another fm radio, shortwave radio or satellite phone and possibly other things, depending on what's going to work in given conditions. On the ground, cell phone is an option too, in the air they may not work as GSM has problems with high speeds.