# What are the meanings of these terms used in ATC ground communications?

Tags: air-traffic-control, phraseology

Regarding ATC ground communications, what/who are the following callees? Are these aircraft, or vehicles, or people?

1. [Airline name] maintenance
2. [Airline name] tug
3. [Airline name] mechanic

Comment: Also related : https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29706/679

Comment: Thanks, these do answer for the first half of my question. But the second half still remains.

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions in one if possible. Since the first half of your question is already answered elsewhere, it might be best to remove that part completely and focus on the second part.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are driving a vehicle anywhere within the movement controlled area of an airport you need to be in contact with the ground controller.

1 & 3 are virtually synonymous, it is a person, a mechanic, working for the named airline's maintenance department, driving a vehicle.

2 is a person driving a aircraft tug vehicle.

Comment: I think it's not the case. From a comment came in for an answer (now deleted) said ATC won't call to people but vehicles or aircraft. And also suggested,

1. An aircraft manned by a mechanic on the ground. Usually calls for repositioning.
2. A tug serves or operated by a particular airline
3. As you said a synonym for the first one.

Comment: @Nipuna, I did not use the term pedestrians, I specified people in vehicles.  (in case that is causing any confusion)  Good point about a mechanic, or other maintenance personnel repositioning an aircraft.  But, it seems you have enough information to clear things up, right?  If you don't like my answer you can always provide your own.  I don't feel compelled to add more detail because it isn't that complicated.

Comment: Hey Michael, I meant nothing offensive. I was just confused earlier.

Comment: I'd imagine it's possible that #2 is not just the tug vehicle, but also a tug with an aircraft attached (such as if the aircraft is being moved from/to a maintenance facility or other non-pushback moves).

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I've got as for an answer. This information was gathered from a comment came in for an answer which is now deleted together with the answer itself.

*This answer needs improvements and confirmation from someone who is more knowledgeable.*

**1. [Airline name] maintenance**
An aircraft manned by a mechanic on the ground. Usually calls for repositioning.

**2. [Airline name] tug**
A tug works for ***or*** operated by the named airline.

**3. [Airline name] mechanic**
A possible synonym for *[Airline name] maintenance*